# Codeforces Bouncing Ball Challenge DP Round 687

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I came across this interesting problem in dynamic programming in today's contest..Unfortunately, could not complete the solution. Test case started failing.

Question:
https://codeforces.com/contest/1456/problem/A

My solution doesn't seem to work from 2nd test case.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer:
Simple top Down DP is my approach.. At any point if we see 0 then either cost x can be spent for adding platform and we move forward k units or cost y can be spent for removing platform from the beginning and we move forward by 1 step as p will move forward 1 unit if 1 is removed before p. But this doesn't work from 2nd test case. Any help would be very much appreciated.

P.S: This is a already over challenge.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BouncingBall {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++) {
            String line1 = br.readLine();
            String[] line1Ip = line1.split(" ");
            int n = Integer.parseInt(line1Ip[0]);
            int p = Integer.parseInt(line1Ip[1]);
            int k = Integer.parseInt(line1Ip[2]);
            String input = br.readLine();
            String[] inputLine = input.split("");
            int[] ip = new int[inputLine.length];
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
                ip[j] = Integer.parseInt(inputLine[j]);
            }
            String[] cost = br.readLine().split(" ");
            int x = Integer.parseInt(cost[0]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(cost[1]);
            int[] dp = new int[ip.length];
            Arrays.fill(dp, -1);
            int minCost = getMinCost(ip, p-1, x, y, k, dp);
            System.out.println(minCost);
        }
    }

    private static int getMinCost(int[] ip, int i, int x, int y, int k, int[] dp) {
        if(i >= ip.length) {
            return 0;
        }
        if(ip[i] == 1) {
            return getMinCost(ip, i+k, x, y, k, dp);
        }
        if(dp[i] != -1) {
            return dp[i];
        }
        dp[i] = Math.min(y + getMinCost(ip, i+1,  x, y, k, dp),
                x + getMinCost(ip, i+k, x, y, k, dp));
        return dp[i];
    }


}
```

**EDIT: Algorithm for my approach :**

My logic is

```
1) if current index element is 1 then we move forward k index
2) if current index is 0 then either
       a) I make current index platform and move k steps forward 
             or
       b) I remove an element from the beginning. So p moves forward 1 step so I start looking at p+1 index
```

I have drawn below overlapping sub-structure. I have used 1-D array to memorize already solved binary sub-problem. Does this algo has any issue ? Above code is based on that.

```
                            0101010101 [p=3][k=2][i=2]
                         /                            \
                      x+                               y+
                     /                                   \  
            010101[i=4]                                   1010101 [i=3]
           x+          y+                                   |
        0101           10101                               10101  
     x+     y+            |                                 |
   01      101           101                                101                  
  x+        |             |                                 |
  X         1             1                                 1
```

Comment: I would add a description of the problem in the body of the question. Links can expire.

Comment: Please do not rely on a link to explain your question.  Always include the necessary information in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to help you debug the algorithm if you provide a more formal outline of your idea in words. For example:

Let's start by focusing only on the removal of the first element, and renumbering, at cost `y`. (1) For each candidate `p` that we get after the next removal, we'd like to know how many platform additions at cost `x` we would need to make. Clearly, if we knew in advance how many removals were optimal, we wouldn't want to add any platforms on a cell that's not in the final sequence of `p, p+k, p+2k...`.

To have a store `num_adds_needed[i]` for (1), we can use a dynamic program. Start from the end and say that:

```
num_adds_needed[i] =
  num_adds_needed[i + k] +
  0 if A[i] == 1 else 1
```

Notice that we don't need anything stored for `i < p`.

Now to calculate the best answer, we can iterate over each candidate `p`, keeping track of how many removals we would need to get to it:

```
Zero removals:

  best = num_adds_needed[p] * x

One removal:

  best = min(
    best,
    y + num_adds_needed[p + 1] * x
  )
  
N removals:

  best = min(
    best,
    N * y + num_adds_needed[p + N] * x
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick answer.. I have added my approach of top-down DP.. By any chance are you able to see any obvious mistake ?

Comment: @Saawan yes, what you labeled as 1) is an obvious mistake. If the current element is 1, we could still have an optimal choice that requires removing and starting the sequence later.

Comment: @Saawan but I think the recursion you have formulated has an additional problem in that it mixes adding cost to branching into different sequences. The optimal task will pick *one and only one* sequence (or potentially all similarly priced sequences) and would not add the cost of a platform to a logical branch that also adds a removal if that platform doesn't belong to the optimal sequence.

Comment: "If the current element is 1, we could still have an optimal choice that requires removing and starting the sequence later" Could you please give an example

Comment: @Saawan sure let's alter one digit in the first example described in the problem: `10 3 2; 0111010101; 2 2`

Comment: Above code gives correct answer; 2 for the above input..

Comment: if I get one input where the above code breaks, It will help me think in the right direction.. codeforces test shows a big input and doesn't show complete input.. please do help; Thanks

Comment: @Saawan `12 2 3; 010001001001; 1 1` if I understand correctly, your method would return an incorrect result of 1, which is not possible.